# What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

Tags: c

I want to know that what is the error in my code.

```
int main () {

long long int number, large_factor=0, i=2;

printf ("Enter a number : ");
scanf ("%ld", &number);

while (number!=1) {

    if (number%i==0) {

        while (number%i==0) {
            printf ("%ld\t", i);
            number/=i;
        }

        large_factor=i;
    }

    i++;
 }

printf ("\n\nThe largest prime factor is : %ld\n\n", large_factor);

return 0;
}
```

This code is running fine for smaller numbers but why it is failing for the large numbers?

Comment: Why are you prompting for an entry and using scanf rather than just taking it as a command line argument?  It would be far more idiomatic to take an argument.

Comment: Do you know what variable size and maximum value is?

Comment: I don't know.  What did your debugger tell you?

Comment: Try using `%lld` instead of `%ld`

Comment: Review your compiler's warning setting.  Good compiler's warn about issues answered by [@iharob](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27730755/2410359).  Turn all warnings on - it saves you time and makes for  better code.

Answer (score 4):

Your format specifier *everywhere* is for `long int` you should use `"%lld"`.

Comment: Using doubles would be a bad idea due the the imprecise nature of them.

Comment: Using double will be a heck ! I was going with a wrong format specifier ! Shitt I don't know why I always do such mistakes !

Answer (score 0):

When I fix the format specifiers it runs fine for 600851475143 giving the largest prime factor 6857.

There must be something else going on. Assuming your compiler is compliant `long long int` should (at minimum) be a 64-bit integer and easily large enough to accommodate that value.

Try

```
printf("long long int max : %lld\n",LLONG_MAX);
```

Having added `#include <limits.h>` at the top.

It should produce a value no less than 9223372036854775807 and probably that exact number.

Here:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    printf("long long int max : %lld\n",LLONG_MAX);

    long long int large_factor=0, i=2;


    long long int number=600851475143;

    while (number!=1) {

        if (number%i==0) {

            while (number%i==0) {
                printf ("%lld\t", i);
                number/=i;
            }

            large_factor=i;
        }

        i++;
     }

    printf ("\n\nThe largest prime factor is : %lld\n\n", large_factor);

    return 0;
}
```